# Can someone explain to me how this is undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, g++, undefined-behavior, compiler-bug

I have this simple program which I compile with -O2.

**Compiler version** : g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

```
#include <cstdlib>

constexpr size_t NUM_ELEMENTS = 10000;

void init(float *a) {
    a[0] = 42;

    size_t i;
    for (i = 1; i < NUM_ELEMENTS - 2; i += 3) {
        a[i] = a[i+1] = a[i+2] = 42;
    }

    while (i < NUM_ELEMENTS) {
        a[i] = 42;
        i++;
    }
}

int main() {
    float a[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    init(a);
    return 0;
}
```

And g++ gives me this (inexplicable to me) warning

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘void init(float*)’:
foo.cpp:14:12: warning: iteration 4611686018427387903 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
   14 |         a[i] = 42;
      |            ^
foo.cpp:13:14: note: within this loop
   13 |     while (i < NUM_ELEMENTS) {
      |            ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I change the while with the equivalent `for (; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)` the warning goes away. If I change the array to global and I just access it in randomize WITHOUT passing it as a parameter, the warning goes away.

I've read similar SO questions which I understand, but this baffles me. If I had to guess, I'd say that g++ knows the while loop will never run (since i == 10000 at the end of the 1st loop) and it does some kind of aggressive transformation that leads to this warning? Help!

Comment: @Eljay: The `for` loop?  The `while` loop?

Comment: @OP: I'm at a loss as well: you're always doing a bounds-check before subscripting the array.  Due to promotion rules, `NUM_ELEMENTS-2` is performed using unsigned arithmetic and can wrap around... but not when `NUM_ELEMENTS` is 10000.  The compiler should in fact generate this sort of pattern automatically from `-funroll-loops`.

Comment: @Eljay this code is essentially a simplification of a program for loop-unrolling that I took from "A Programmer's Perspective". I'm 99.9% sure the index checks are correct. However, I did add the assert to the loop and I see no abort.

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah and if I change the step to +2 and adjust the indexes accordingly, so that the while loop again does not run, I don't get the warning. It's truly baffling.

Comment: The "bad" iteration is 0x3FFF'FFFF'FFFF'FFFF.... it's almost like g++ has determined that there are a fixed number of iterations here (true), tried to calculate the number of iterations, and caused integer wraparound in that calculation.

Comment: I suggest reporting this as a compiler bug.

Comment: To help the compiler developers, can you check whether the bug is sensitive to the constexpr value of `NUM_ELEMENTS`?  For example, does it happen for 9999 and 10001?  How about 10003?

Comment: What version of g++ are you using?

Comment: Also if the array element type changes to double, does the iteration get cut in half from 0x3FFF'FFFF'FFFF'FFFF to 0x1FFF'FFFF'FFFF'FFFF ?

Comment: @BenVoigt it happens for 9999 and 10001 too (changing starting index to 0 and 2 respectively to make sure while should not run). And yes, changing to double seems to halve(?) the iteration num to 2305843009213693951.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a duplicate of [a known bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=100801) in gcc that has to do with `-Waggressive-loop-optimizations`. But given that your example is much simpler than those I have seen in [duplicates](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=83234) of that bug, I suggest you report the example to the confirmed bug report (see link).

Interestingly, this problem appears to exist only for `-O2`, not for `-O1` and `-O3` in the existing reports.

Comment: The repro in Comment #3 at that link looks considerably simpler.

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh yes, you could consider that example to be smaller, but simpler, I'm not sure. The fact that we have an array with a controlled size here makes it more perplexing in my eyes. Comment #3 doesn't specify where the array comes from. At any rate, additional examples probably do not hurt.

Comment: @bitmask feel free to add this example. I can't since account creation is restricted (for bugzilla)